# Singular vs Plural Keywords

Tags: seo, keyword

I was looking for a concrete answer on whether i should optimize my pages for singular or plural version of target keyword. Let me give an example:

I have a computers website and from homepage i have links for my primary categories / keywords:

Processors
Motherboards
Printers
Scanners
etc.....

Now with google adwords tool, i come to know that "Processor" is searched much more than the plural version "Processors". Now some questions arise to improve my SEO efforts:

1. Should i use singular version of the keyword?
2. If i use the plural version, does it optimizes for both the singular and plural searches as "Processor" is logically contained within "Processors" ?
3. What is best strategy/practice to deal with the situation.

Thanks
Raheel

Comment: Not sure this is appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Well Google & Co. do differentiate between singular and plural forms. You may have to choose one which is more important to you and optimize for it or apply some more effort to optimize separately for both forms.

Answer (score 1):

There are some schools of thought that state optimizing for both is the best solution:  http://www.reflectionsfromtheriver.com/2009/05/singular-vs-plural-keywords-seo-opportunities/